# notebook==5.7.4 cannot be installed on this environment (anaconda navigator)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo2xB.png)

hi
i'm using anaconda navigator
and i wanna install jupyter notebook on my environment
but i cannot install notebook cause this alert said that i should used another environment for installing jupyter notebook
"notebook==5.7.4 cannot be installed on this environment (anaconda navigator)"
i'm not sure why it is showed and why i can't install jupyter on my anaconda virtual environment.
please give me any comments and thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please describe what you have done to get there?

Comment: @AlexVorndran I'm using anaconda navigator. and it gave me an install button of jupyter notebook. it was activated but i could not install jupyter notebook on my environment. :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate your enviorment? If yes try `conda install -c anaconda jupyter` if not `activate <name>`

Comment: sure. i activated my own environment and `conda install -c anaconda jupyter` is failed with CondaHTTPError. I'll search more about this error. thank you for your comment!

Comment: I solve this problem after updating anaconda navigator. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by updating anaconada.The update command is:
(1): conda update conda
(2):conda update anaconda